# Excel specific formula required based on date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula

I am looking to find a formula to show a value or text for those who have "left" if the current month is no longer listed against their name, as well as if the current month is listed they are still "active"

see image example of data

***Employee Names & Dates Image:***

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FILTER($B$2:$B$15,($A$2:$A$15=F2)*(MONTH($B$2:$B$15)=MONTH(TODAY())),"Left")),"Active","Left")
```

For any version of excel you can use-

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$15,F2,$B$2:$B$15,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,$B$2:$B$15,"<="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))>0,"Active","Left")
```

[image]

Comment: additional, what would be an alternative for it to be based on previous month not current month. I.e September?

Comment: Then it would be `=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$15,F2,$B$2:$B$15,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1,$B$2:$B$15,"<="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1))>0,"Active","Left")`